# os x mountain lion with homebrew and EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit) not playing nice

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, enthought

OS X Mountain Lion with Homebrew package manager and Python 2.7.3 -- EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit) are not playing nice together. Please see the details shown below. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
cachapa

```
    Last login: Tue Sep 24 05:28:30 on ttys004 
    ~ ❯❯❯ echo $PATH 
    /Users/mlb/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:
    /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin 

    ~ ❯❯❯ which python 
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python 

    ~ ❯❯❯ python --version 
    Python 2.7.3 -- EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit) 

    ~ ❯❯❯ brew doctor 
    Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories. 
    `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if 
    software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when 
    compiling and linking.

    Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via 
    Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided 
    script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/gdal-config 
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python-config 
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python2-config 
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python2.7-config 
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/xml2-config 
    /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/xslt-config

    Warning: Enthought Python was found in your PATH. 
    This can cause build problems, as this software installs its own 
    copies of iconv and libxml2 into directories that are picked up by 
    other build systems.
```

Comment: so, how exactly are they "not playing nice together" other than that warning message?

Comment: Homebrew states that this can cause build problems, as this software (EPD)installs its own copies of iconv and libxml2 into directories that are picked up by other build systems.

Comment: The easiest solution is to tweak PATH depending on your immediate needs. If homebrew wants system python on the path, give it to it. For your scientific python work, put EPD on the Path. Another alternative is to install Enthought Canopy instead of EPD, and decline its offer to be the default Python -- just run its Python inside its own GUI.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for responding to my request for help. If look at the PATH that I posted you will see that the path to EPD comes after the path that Homebrew makes its claim to but Homebrew complains.

Since I find Homebrew Python unacceptable for numerical analysis I may have to dump the Homebrew Package Manager because of little or no support.

I did a standard install of canopy-1.1.0-full-osx-64 and it appears that Homebrew is playing nice. I haven't tried using its command line setup which I prefer.

Thanks again for your input.

Regards,
cachapa